# How to Create a Shortcut to put a frame around an equation

Tags: formatting, text-formatting

I use mathematica for typing Physics and other notes. For important equations, I prefer to put a box around them. To do so I use either:

- Insert-> Typesetting -> Add Frame from the menubar
- Palette -> Writing Assistant -> Writing and Formatting -> Cell Properties -> Frame

This is tedious when you are rapidly taking notes. I desire to be able to assign the command(s) to a shortcut key. Is there a function or command that I could assign to a shortcut key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a keyboard short-cut to a add a frame:

Select any expression or cell breacket, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> then hit <kbd>`t`</kbd> and <kbd>`m`</kbd>:

[image]

This works on Windows. On Mac, use <kbd>Option</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

**Note:** The documentation page [Insert >> Typesetting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/Typesetting.html) does not mention this shortcut. There is also no indication of this keyboard shortcut in the `Insert` menu and `Typesetting` submenu:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly.